# binding data in asp c# like php, is that possible?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I am new to asp.net, and what I want to know is how to bind data directly into a custom div
without using things such as data grid or any other thing, let's say I want to bind a description for something stored in my sql DB.

In PHP i used to do this:

```
<p>
<?php echo $row_RecordSetName['col']; ?>
</p>
```

But how to do in asp.net using C# in a webform?

I tried to do it in a dataset thing like so but it keeps giving errors:

```
<p>
<%= Dataset.DB[0].colNAME.ToString() %>
</p>
```

as well as i tried doing the following stupid way :

```
try
{
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mallsdb where mall_un='" + i + "'", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        MallsDS tds = new MallsDS();
        da.Fill(tds, tds.Tables[0].TableName);


        string MallPIC = Convert.ToString(tds.mallsdb[0].mall_pic);
        string MallNAME = Convert.ToString(tds.mallsdb[0].mall_name);
        string MallUn = Convert.ToString(tds.mallsdb[0].mall_un);

        string MallDESP;
        string check_desp = Convert.ToString(tds.mallsdb[0].mall_desp);

        if (check_desp.Length < 50)
        {
            MallDESP = check_desp;
        }
        else
        {
            string under = check_desp.Substring(0, 30);
            MallDESP = under + "....";
        }


        Result[i] = "<div class='malls'>" + "<img src='images/" + MallPIC + "' width='250' height='250' />" + "<a class='namer' href='malls_private.aspx?mall_un=" + MallUn + "'><h1>" + MallNAME + "</h1></a><p>" + MallDESP + "</p></div>";


    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
    }


    Label1.Text = Result[1];
    Label2.Text = Result[2];
    Label3.Text = Result[3];
    Label4.Text = Result[4];
    Label5.Text = Result[5];
    Label6.Text = Result[6];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks friends and in the following is the answer to my question, as i read about it in microsoft MSDN.

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<script runat="server">
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
SqlConnection cnn = new 
SqlConnection("server=(local);database=pubs;Integrated Security=SSPI"); 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from authors", cnn); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
da.Fill(ds, "authors"); 
Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables["authors"];
Repeater1.DataBind();
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form id="WebForm2" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"au_id") %><br>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can do something like `<div runat='server' id='divWhateverDiv'>` in the aspx and then in the actual C# code (not in the aspx itself) you can reference the div element as a normal C# variable by its id, and do something like `divWhateverDiv.innerHTML = "whatever";`  Visual Studio's intellisense will help you with the actual capitialization of the members and such.  What you're trying to do is more like old asp than asp.net

Comment: thank you, but i told you am new and i dont know anything in asp.net please could u provide an example in which am using a data set.

Comment: If you are actually using Visual Studio to make a project rather than just opening notepad and making a .asp, then you ought to figure this out in about an hour of messing with it, since it will automatically put in some of this stuff just by you dragging a widget onto your view.

Comment: well, ive been massing with it for a week and what i finally did in the cs file is a FOR loop which repeats the commands but this is limited and i have put in the aspx file labels and assigned there text values in the loop and to make it true i have initialized an array in which filled by the loop and then assigns the labels text value, i know it all massed up